# Android Intent Se cierra

Tags: android, android-intent

Quiero hacer un código donde al dar click en el botón, me lleve a otro. Y al darle click en el botón regresar no se pierdan los datos y los devuelva.

el problema es cuando intento hacer que los datos del segundo activity retornen a main activiy, se me cierra la app.

Por eso creo que el error esta al crear el intent, cuando comento la parte bundle del main activity, la app abre, pero al crear el bundle, o sea al recibir los datos, no funciona

Llevo tiempo intentando

Le agradezco al que me pueda ayudar

el error aparece cuando intento devolverme al primer activity, no se si tiene que estar primero el metodo bundle en el código

Gracias de antemano

```
package com.niccode.desarrollounaapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker;
import com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button Siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Siguiente);

        final EditText etName         = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tiNombreCompleto);
        final EditText etFecha       = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Calendario);
        final EditText etTelefono    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tiTelefono);
        final EditText etEmail       = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tiEmail);
        final EditText etDescripcion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tiDescripcionContacto);


        MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        builder.setTitleText(getResources().getString(R.string.date1));

        final MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        etFecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");

            }
        });

        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
                etFecha.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
            }
        });


        Siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Confirmar_Datos.class);

                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pname), etName.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pdate),  etFecha.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono), etTelefono.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail),  etEmail.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pDescripcion),  etDescripcion.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            }
        });

        Bundle para_back = getIntent().getExtras();

        assert para_back != null;
        final String nombre_return      = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtname));
        final String fecha_return       = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtdate));
        final String telefono_return    = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtelefono));
        final String email_return       = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtemail));
        final String descripcion_return = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtDescripcion));

        etName.setText(nombre_return);
        etFecha.setText(fecha_return);
        etTelefono.setText(telefono_return);
        etEmail.setText(email_return);
        etDescripcion.setText(descripcion_return);
    }
}
```

Segundo activity

```
package com.niccode.desarrollounaapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Confirmar_Datos extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.confirmar_datos);

        Button Regresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regresar);

        Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
        assert parametros != null;
        final String str_nombre = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pname));
        final String str_fecha = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pdate));
        final String str_telefono = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono));
        final String str_email = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail));
        final String str_descripcion = parametros.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.pDescripcion));


        final TextView tvnombre = findViewById(R.id.Nombre_Completo_Confirmado);
        final TextView tvfecha  = findViewById(R.id.fecha_de_nacimiento_Confirmado);
        final TextView tvTelefono  = findViewById(R.id.tel_Confirmado);
        final TextView tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.mail_Confirmado);
        final TextView tvDescripcion = findViewById(R.id.Descripcion_Confirmado);

        tvnombre.setText(str_nombre);
        tvfecha.setText(str_fecha);
        tvTelefono.setText( str_telefono);
        tvEmail.setText(str_email);
        tvDescripcion.setText(str_descripcion);



        Regresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent regresar = new Intent (Confirmar_Datos.this, MainActivity.class);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtname) , str_nombre);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtdate), str_fecha);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtelefono), str_telefono);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtemail), str_email);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtDescripcion), str_descripcion);
               startActivity(regresar);
            }
        });


        }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Confirmar_Datos.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
    }
```

String file

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">DesarrolloUnaApp</string>
    <string name="nombre_completo">Nombre Completo</string>
    <string name="telefono">Teléfono</string>
    <string name="email">  Email</string>
    <string name="descripcion_contacto">Descripción del Contacto</string>
    <string name="siguiente">Siguiente</string>
    <string name="date1">Fecha de Nacimiento</string>
    <string name="confirmar">Confirmar Datos</string>
    <string name="pname">Name</string>
    <string name="pdate">Date</string>
    <string name="ptelefono">Telefono</string>
    <string name="pemail">Email</string>
    <string name="pDescripcion">Descripcion</string>
    <string name="editar_datos">Editar Datos</string>
    <string name="tvdate">Date : </string>
    <string name="tvtelefono">Telefono : </string>
    <string name="tvemail">Email : </string>
    <string name="tvDescripcion">Descripcion : </string>

    <string name="rtname">Nombre</string>
    <string name="rtdate">Fecha</string>
    <string name="rtelefono">Telefono</string>
    <string name="rtemail">Email</string>
    <string name="rtDescripcion">Descripcion</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar lo que te aparece en el log cuando vuelves del segundo activity al primero para poder ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de obtener los extras en cada inicio de tu activity, no solo cuando regresa de la segunda activity.

Agrega una condicion para saber si tu activity esta recibiendo parametros

```
Bundle para_back = getIntent().getExtras();
if(para_back!=null){//Si hay parametros
    final String nombre_return =para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtname));
    final String fecha_return       = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtdate));
    final String telefono_return    = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtelefono));
    final String email_return       = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtemail));
    final String descripcion_return = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtDescripcion));
    
    etName.setText(nombre_return);
    etFecha.setText(fecha_return);
    etTelefono.setText(telefono_return);
    etEmail.setText(email_return);
    etDescripcion.setText(descripcion_return);
}
```

Tambien puedes iniciar tu segundo activity con startActivityForResult y esperar el resultado en el metodo onActivityResult

```
Siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Confirmar_Datos.class);

                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pname), etName.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pdate),  etFecha.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.ptelefono), etTelefono.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pemail),  etEmail.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.pDescripcion),  etDescripcion.getText().toString());

                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            }
        });
```

Segundo Activity:

```
Regresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent regresar = new Intent();
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtname) , str_nombre);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtdate), str_fecha);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtelefono), str_telefono);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtemail), str_email);
               regresar.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.rtDescripcion), str_descripcion);
               setResult(200,regresar);
               finish()
            }
        });
```

De vuetla al primer activity

```
@override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == 1) {
             if (resultCode == 200) {
                 // Aqui puedes obtener los parametros de regreso
                 Bundle para_back=data.getExtras()
                 String nombre_return      = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtname));
                 String fecha_return       = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtdate));
                 String telefono_return    = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtelefono));
                 String email_return       = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtemail));
                 String descripcion_return = para_back.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.rtDescripcion));
                 //Declara tus editText como propiedades de tu Activity para que puedas acceder a ellos desde aqui
                 etName.setText(nombre_return);
                 etFecha.setText(fecha_return);
                 etTelefono.setText(telefono_return);
                 etEmail.setText(email_return);
                 etDescripcion.setText(descripcion_return);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```